# Lookup With Picker Not Working

Tags: document-library, lookup-column

I have a document library on SharePoint 2013 that has a column that is defined as type "Lookup with Picker" that looks at a list within the sub site.

[image]

I have no idea if this is a SharePoint component or a third party plugin. When I click on the browse button above, the icon on the right, I get a an error, something went wrong along with a correlation ID. I've searched the logs for the correlation ID and found this message.

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/Picker.aspx, Error=Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,

Can anyone offer some insight into this error? Is picker.aspx a SharePoint component or a third party plugin and how can I restore/reinstall it.

On the flip side if I type the name of a supplier above and click resolve, the icon on the left, it will resolve the supplier name from the list if it exists. Lookup with picker doesn't work anywhere across the SharePoint site, there is a people picker item that does work though.

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of authentication are you using?

Comment: We are using single sign on, if that's what you need to know. In the log there is and Authentication Authorization category that says. `Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0`, if that helps.

Comment: `iLoveSharePoint.Fields.LookupFieldWithPicker.wsp` is the solution for this feature. It is 3rd party

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as a third part component, that could be obsolete and not working on SharePoint 2013. From error description it looks like it want's to load SharePoint 2010 dll `Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0`.

You should review your farm solutions in Central Admin and check that third part component and look how to update it to SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Thanks. The upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 wasn't done correctly as I've had to work with other 3rd party supplier to get there applications working correctly.